# Android - Snackbar between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-snackbar, snackbar

How i can show snackbar in **Activity A** (coordinatorLayout is here) when my callback in **Activity B** is done ? Snackbar need my coordinatorLayout but i can't give it from Activity B..

Activity B :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == android.R.id.home) {
        this.finish();
        return true;
    } else if(id == R.id.action_add) {
        callAddObject();
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void callAddObject() {
    [...]
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
            // show snackbar in Activity A
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().string());
            // show snackbar in Activity A
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can have only 1 Activity on the screen.

Comment: Yes for sure, but i can't do something like a listener to warn Activity A when Activity B is done or something else ?

Comment: It could be that your problem is solvable in some other way as Gabriele's comment hints. What do your 2 Activities do and why do they want to create a snackbar in the other?

Comment: Activity B is a form and when form is submit i would like to close B and add snackbar in A to say success or error. If isn't possible i can also just add snackbar in B and redirect to A after..

Comment: Can you do it on onActivityResult?

Answer (score 6):

You should open Activity B from Activity A like

```
startActivityForResult(activityBIntent, FORM_REQUEST_CODE);
```

then when your form is submitted, finish Activity B with a result

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
    // You might not want to finish the activity here, instead, you can show an error here
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().string());
    setResult(FORM_SUBMITTED);
    finish();
}
```

and react to that back in Activity A like

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FORM_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == ActivityB.FORM_SUBMITTED) {
                Snackbar.make(mView, "Form submitted", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}
```

---

Alternative solution would be to make the call to server in, say, an IntentService and use some kind of **event bus** (i.e. [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)) to send an event to Activity A as soon as the call finishes.